# Strange ifstream access violation under Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ifstream, g++4.8

I have this piece of code working on Linux with g++:

```
GLuint Shader::initShader_(GLenum shaderType, const std::string& shaderFilename)
{
    std::ifstream inputFile(shaderFilename.c_str());
    if (inputFile.is_open() == false)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Shader " << shaderFilename << " doesn't exist!";
        print(LOG_LEVEL::ERROR, oss.str());
    }
    ...
}
```

where the three dots represent some code. On both g++ and Visual Studio (2012) the code compiles. But with Visual Studio, the first line throws an access violation exception. This actually happens when opening the file, and the debugger redirects me to *do_always_noconv* but I do not understand the problem.

The string containing the filename is valid and the file the program is trying to open is in the good directory, and the debugger works in this directory. I guess the problem does not come from the file itself, because if the stream cannot open it then I could still enter the next line without an access violation.

Does anyone already encountered this problem or has an idea? Again it worked without any problem on Linux with g++.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An access violation exception doesn't indicate a problem with the file, but with the in-memory representation of the ifstream object or the string. Start looking for memory corruption.

Be sure you're referencing the correct GLSDK libraries for your build type. e.g. debug builds should reference debug libraries and release builds should reference release libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am building the project in debug mode, and the libraries are for the debug mode (there is a d at the end of the microsoft libs).

Comment: I really do not understand: I created a project with the same libs and  properties with just a few lines to test strings and ifstreams and it works very well...

Comment: I meant the OpenGL SDK libraries, but it is good to verify the Microsoft ones as well.
If you've verified all your libs are correct for your project type, then the memory corruption must be elsewhere. start looking for places where you write to arrays and verify the lengths of those writes. Consider using Application Verifier to check your memory usage.

Comment: Dear PaulH, thanks for your help! I checked the libraries, no problem. I also used Application Verifier but it didn't tell me more (as far as I understand). However, following your question I commented out some array code I wrote and there is no problem anymore although the two pieces of code are totally unrelated. I guess it has something to do with memory that I do not understand. I will continue to search for the bug. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear PaulH, I solved the problem, it was with my array code, many thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Please use the green check-mark to indicate your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

As PaulH suggested above, I checked some array code that I wrote recently and the error came from some wrong indices and pointers. However I still do not understand why the errors in the array code have something to do with the ifstream. Thanks to PaulH!

Comment: The bug in your code overwrote some part of the std::string or std::ifstream objects such that when you went to use those objects, they were no longer valid and caused the access violation.